# Is there an NOAA/NWS API that provides graphical products?

Tags: api, weather

I am trying to find out if the NWS api has graphical products available. I have explored the api at the following link quite thoroughly:

https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api

What I am looking for is something that might return a link to, or an image of something like the storm prediction center two day outlook:

https://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/outlook/day2otlk.html

And I would be looking to get the main image there:

https://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/outlook/day2otlk_1730.gif?1540077375524

I feel like this information would be provided, but I can't seem to find it or I am not searching for the right terms!

I am hoping it is available via some api as I was trying to avoid crawling.

Comment: NOAA actually has more than one API available - one of the others may do what you want easily. https://www.programmableweb.com/api/noaa-national-weather-service-nws